# What is Amazon Aws?

Tags: amazon, amazon-aws

What is Amazon Aws? Is it hosting service provided by Amazon? Is Twitpic hosted by AmazonAws? How much it cost (I couldnt find on their site)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS is [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/). It's the umbrella term that covers a range of (separately priced) web services from Amazon. The best known services are

- [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) Simple Storage Service, Amazon's "cloud file system" if you like.
- [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) Elastic Compute Cloud, their scalable web server service for running your own web apps.
- [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/), a scalable and simple (non-relational) database system.

There's quite a bit to AWS -- it's not a single product but a quite large suite of services. Costs vary depending on the service and your usage of it. Twitter has indeed used S3 in the past (not sure if they still do).

Answer (score 0):

AWS is a Amazon web service, a cloud platform provided by Amazon. A widely listed services and a vivid market place. this platform provides you great flexibility to expand as your business grows. As well as a haven for the administrated where they can control everything both traditional as well as modern GUI way.

> - For understanding the cost you can get more understanding in the simple [Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)
> - [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)
>
> For Benefits you can look into there benefits page.